# link containers with the docker python API

Tags: python, dockerpy

I want to use the docker python API (`pip install docker-py`) to create a container and link it to an existing container which I created with docker-compose.

Using the command line this is easy:

`docker run --link EXISTING_CONTAINER:LINK_NAME mycontainer:mytag`

But using the docker API I'm stuck. I think that I have to use the `docker.Client().create_container()` method, which takes an - undocumented - parameter `links=`. (I strongly think the documentation is pretty much incomplete ...).

I tried reading the docker-compose code, and this seems to use the `links=` parameter, but I could not figure out how.

My initial attempt did not work:

`client_obj.create_container(..., links=(('EXISTING_CONTAINER', 'LINK_NAME'),))`

... which is what I think the docker-compose code is doing.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/docker/docker-py

> A Python library for the Docker Remote API. It does everything the
>   docker command does, but from within Python – run containers, manage
>   them, pull/push images, etc.

[create_container](http://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#create_container):

```
Creates a container that can then be .start() ed. 
Parameters are similar to those for the docker run 
command except it doesn't support the attach options (-a).
```

The [source code of create_container](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/035e9e1c911d44167f62081a01d2b167270ee0f1/docker/api/container.py#L95)

```
def create_container(self, image, command=None, hostname=None, user=None,
                     detach=False, stdin_open=False, tty=False,
                     mem_limit=None, ports=None, environment=None,
                     dns=None, volumes=None, volumes_from=None,
                     network_disabled=False, name=None, entrypoint=None,
                     cpu_shares=None, working_dir=None, domainname=None,
                     memswap_limit=None, cpuset=None, host_config=None,
                     mac_address=None, labels=None, volume_driver=None,
                     stop_signal=None, networking_config=None):
```

But I found `links` at [start function](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/035e9e1c911d44167f62081a01d2b167270ee0f1/docker/api/container.py#L301):

```
def start(self, container, binds=None, port_bindings=None, lxc_conf=None,
          publish_all_ports=None, links=None, privileged=None,
          dns=None, dns_search=None, volumes_from=None, network_mode=None,
          restart_policy=None, cap_add=None, cap_drop=None, devices=None,
          extra_hosts=None, read_only=None, pid_mode=None, ipc_mode=None,
          security_opt=None, ulimits=None):
```

So I think you should:

```
from docker import Client
>>> cli = Client(base_url='tcp://127.0.0.1:2375')
>>> container = cli.create_container(
...     image='busybox:latest',
...     command='/bin/sleep 30')
>>> response = cli.start(container=container.get('Id'),links=[('EXISTING_CONTAINER', 'LINK_NAME')])
```

## The working example (DO)

I am using CoreOS on DO:

1. run docker container and mount inside the `/var/run/docker.sock`
   from host
2. install tools
3. run test container `EXISTING_CONTAINER`
4. run python example

The set of commands:

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:12.04 bash
apt-get update;apt-get install python-pip -y;pip install docker-py
docker run -d --name EXISTING_CONTAINER busybox   sh -c "while true; do sleep 1;done"
```

**Python example**

```
from docker import Client
cli = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock', version='auto')
container = cli.create_container(
image='busybox:latest',
command='/bin/sleep 30')
response = cli.start(container=container.get('Id'),links=(('EXISTING_CONTAINER', 'LINK_NAME'))
```

The result on host:

```
wp-coreos-512mb-ams2-01 ~ # docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2f58e661579d        busybox             "sh -c 'while true; d"   23 seconds ago      Up 22 seconds                           EXISTING_CONTAINER
6f08dd3f5017        busybox:latest      "/bin/sleep 30"          9 minutes ago       Up 5 seconds                            condescending_brown
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried exactly that, and it does not work. Did you try this and it worked for you? Then I might have made another mistake.

Comment: This solution is deprecated, the sdk for python does not allow configuration at start anymore .. :s

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the networking documentation for docker-py is seriously lacking - the maintainers agree (https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/982 for a global alias example).

Note that Valeriy's answer above will create a legacy link, which might (will in my case) lead to issues if you use a non-default network such as the ones created by docker-compose.

In any case, adding parameters to `Client.start` is [depreciated](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docs/hostconfig.md).

The new way to do this can be found in the unitttest: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/tests/integration/network_test.py#L190-213

```
@requires_api_version('1.22')
def test_create_with_links(self):
    net_name, net_id = self.create_network()

    container = self.create_and_start(
        host_config=self.client.create_host_config(network_mode=net_name),
        networking_config=self.client.create_networking_config({
            net_name: self.client.create_endpoint_config(
                links=[('docker-py-test-upstream', 'bar')],
            ),
        }),
    )

    container_data = self.client.inspect_container(container)
    self.assertEqual(
        container_data['NetworkSettings']['Networks'][net_name]['Links'],
        ['docker-py-test-upstream:bar'])

    self.create_and_start(
        name='docker-py-test-upstream',
        host_config=self.client.create_host_config(network_mode=net_name),
    )

    self.execute(container, ['nslookup', 'bar'])
```

Valeriy's Example would then look as follows:

**Python Example**

```
from docker import Client
cli = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock', version='auto')

# Note: 'bridge' is the default network
net_config = cli.create_networking_config(
        {'bridge': self.docker_client.create_endpoint_config(
            links=[('EXISTING_CONTAINER', 'LINK_NAME')]
        )}
    )

container = cli.create_container(
  image='busybox:latest',
  command='/bin/sleep 30',
  network_configuration=net_config 
)
response = cli.start(container=container.get('Id'))
```

I have not tested this specific code, but this is the way I have been able to connect a new container to an existing container, whereas the existing one had been created by compose into a network "project_default"

You might also want to check [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/) for more information and background.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the current working way to do it.

```
links=[('postgres-modeldb', 'modeldb'),('postgres-userdb', 'userdb'),('redis-workerdb', 'workerdb')]

host_config = client.create_host_config(
    links=links
)

networking_config = client.create_networking_config({
    'my-net': client.create_endpoint_config(
        links=links
    )
})

container = client.create_container(
    image='josepainumkal/vwadaptor:jose_toolUI',
    name=container_name,
    host_config=host_config,
    networking_config = networking_config
) 

response = client.start(container=container.get('Id'))
```

Comment: The example is not runnable. If you would make the example work I would be glad to upvote, but sadly not for broken pseudo-code